# uwsgi complains about python application not found

Tags: ubuntu, python, uwsgi

looks like quite common with uWSGI application, but still can't find any valuable solution.

I ma working on ubuntu 12.04 with uwsgi 1.0.3 and python2.7

Here is my config.ini file:

```
  [uwsgi]
  uid = www-data
  gid = www-data
  pythonpath = /path/to/my/application
  plugins = python27
  module = launcher.py
  workers = 2
  vacuum = True
  max-requests = 1000000
  harakiri = 120
  harakiri-verbose = true
  need-app = true
  buffer-size = 32768
  listen = 200
  master-as-root = true
  max-fd = 10240
  #memory-report = true
  #stats = /tmp/stats.socket
  chown-socket = www-data
```

All I got from the log files is:

```
  [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini
  [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/my_application.ini
```

I don't find any way to launch it manually (on foreground, without daemonizing; I have read [the doc here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html) but the option --wsgi-file to sepcify the configuration file does not work) or to increase the verbosity.

I have spend hours parsing google and the uwsgi doc to find my way out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

It looks like uwsgi is starting now, and loading the cherrypy application behind. But at this point, it crashes with the error message:

```
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[06/May/2014:14:40:57] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[06/May/2014:14:40:57] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[06/May/2014:14:40:57] ENGINE Serving on 127.0.0.1:8080
[06/May/2014:14:40:57] ENGINE Bus STARTED
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x201c680 pid: 9890 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 9890)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 9940, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 9941, cores: 1)
metrics collector thread started
invalid signal timer syntax, must be: <signal> <seconds>
VACUUM: unix socket /run/uwsgi/app/uwsgi/socket removed.
root@test:/var/www/ce1sus# Tue May  6 14:40:57 2014 - uWSGI worker 1 screams: UAAAAAAH my master disconnected: i will kill myself !!!
Tue May  6 14:40:57 2014 - uWSGI worker 2 screams: UAAAAAAH my master disconnected: i will kill myself !!!
```

I run this command:

```
uwsgi my_application.ini
```

My uwsgi version is now 2.0.4;

Do I have missed some step somewhere?
Many thanks for your help

Comment: stop using such outdated package with a configuration that hides all of the internals. Uninstall uwsgi debian/ubuntu packages and follow (step by step) the official quickstart: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

Comment: Many thanks! I will try all that tomorrow and keep you in touch with it

Comment: I have upgraded my uwsgi to version 2.0.4; I have edited the question to reflect my progress and how it crashes now. Thanks for any tip or advice you could make.